# Akka messages wait in mailbox even when no messages are currently being processed by the actor

Tags: azure-web-app-service, akka, actor, akka.net

I'm having an issue where every so often Akka messages are being held in an actor's mailbox for longer than necessary, sometimes for up to around 3 seconds.

This is only happening when I run the app (ASP.NET web app) in Azure - there are no delays when I run the code on my laptop.

The app is fairly lightweight, and the CPU and memory on the service plan never go above 60% and 70% respectively. I even tried temporarily upgrading the service plan but that had no impact on the wait times.

I've added in some custom logging to flag when a message has waited in the mailbox for a significant amount of time. (Note the ordering is in descending timestamp)

[image: Application Insights logs]

I've highlighted the messages that are causing the issue - these ones are NOT be waiting for a previous message to finish processing in the actor, so for these the *MessageEntered* time should be the same as the *MessageCreated* time.

I'm wondering if there is some kind of thread limit being hit within the app, as lots of other actors are running threads in parallel...?

Any ideas on what's going on / how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm admittedly not familiar with Akka.Net, but on Akka JVM, this would be setting off my thread starvation spidey sense.  I don't know what tooling Akka.Net has around detecting thread starvation, but you can implement a rudimentary thread starvation detector.

Comment: Basic idea, from looking at the Akka.Net API docs would be to periodically `Schedule` an `Action` on the relevant `Dispatcher`s.  The action compares the current time to the deadline for when it should have started to execute: if it's after the deadline, make some noise in the logs/console/etc.

Comment: From "some kind of thread limit being hit within the app, as lots of other actors are running threads in parallel", that really leads me to believe it's thread starvation.  If actors are executing blocking code, you'll want to move those actors into a dispatcher suitable for that (e.g. one with a lot of threads, since most of them will be blocked) and be careful that those actors don't use a lot of CPU to process messages.  If it's actors performing long computations ("overlong work units"), then I'd suggest looking for places to yield CPU (e.g. send state in a message-to-self).

Comment: ^^^ at least that's what I'd do on Akka JVM... from https://getakka.net/articles/actors/dispatchers.html it looks like .Net has a slightly different threading model

Comment: Thanks @LeviRamsey I hadn't come across dispatchers before. Although I've now added the thread count to each of those warning log messages, and the count tends to only be in the range of 7 to 10. Also I don't understand why the thread behaviour would be any different on my laptop and on Azure. I'll try playing around with the dispatcher configuration and see if that changes anything